# How to include a parent object when serializing a Django Model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two simple models with a foreign key relation like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

The current `rest_framework`-based serializers look like this:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Foo
        fields = ('id', 'code')


class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Bar
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'description')
```

So a GET request for a `Bar` will return something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "foo": 2,
    "description": "[…]"
}
```

**How do I change `BarSerializer` to instead return the full `Foo` object,** like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "foo": {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "[…]"
    },
    "description": "[…]"
}
```

?

Keep in mind I still need to be able to create a `Bar` by providing only a `description` and `Foo` ID. I've tried various things including specifying `foo = FooSerializer()` in `BarSerializer`. The problem is that when I want to create a new `Bar` and link it to an *existing* `Foo` as before, it complains that I've not provided `Foo`'s `code` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simple and Elegant solution

override **`to_represention()`** method as,

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Bar
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'description')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['foo'] = FooSerializer(instance.foo).data
        return data
```

---

#### Orginal version

use **`depth=1`** in **`BarSerializer`** serializer

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Bar
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'description')
        depth = 1
```

**Reference**
1. [**`depth`** [DRF-Doc]](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

**Update-1**
Use ***Two different Serializers*** for Read and Write operations.

```
class BarWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'description')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['foo'] = FooSerializer(instance.foo).data
        return data


class BarReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'description')
        depth = 1
```

and in your views, override the **`get_serializer_class()`** method as,

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class SampleViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Bar.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return BarWriteSerializer
        return BarReadSerializer
```

The payload to use while `Bar` creation,

```
{
    "foo":1,# The "pk" of "Foo" instance
    "description":"bar description"
}
```

Comment: @l0b0 Updated the answer

Comment: updated the answer. (override **`to_representation()`** method of 
 **`BarWriteSerializer`** class )

Comment: Yeah. I missed that point. Anyway, see my first portion of the answer. That's may be the shortest path

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Foo
        fields = ('id', 'code')


class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer(models.Foo.objects.all(), read_only=True)
    foo_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source='foo',
        queryset=models.Foo.objects.all(),
        write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Bar
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'foo_id', 'description')
```

Use a nested serializer as `read_only` to get the full `Foo` object.
Use a `write_only` field `foo_id` to use it for create/update.

Now, your request data will look like:

`{ 'foo_id': 1, 'description': 'foo bar' }`

Alternatively, if you dont want two fields, one for read and another for write, you can override the `create`/`update` methods of the serializer to capture the `foo`'s id.

**Example**:

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer(Foo.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = models.Bar
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'description')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        foo = validated_data.pop('foo')
        bar = Bar.objects.create(
            foo=foo.id,
            **validated_data
        )
        return bar

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        foo = validated_data.pop('foo')
        instance.foo = foo
        instance.update(
            **validated_data
        )
        return instance
```

The request data, in this case, will be:

`{ 'foo': {'id': '1', 'code': 'AAA'}, 'description': 'foo bar' }`